# Speed=mass=time?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, mass, spacetime, reference-frames

1. I was wondering why objects gain mass with speed?
2. How can we measure speed if there is no truly stationary point to measure from?
3. And if an object comes to a stand still will it loose its mass?
4. Also how would time be affected both at (near) light speed and at a complete stand still.
5. One more thought. Could we reach the speed of light as viewed from Earth if we set the center of the universe as our destination?
6. As I understand it we are moving away from this point quit fast and how do we know this point is not moving it self?

Comment: 1, 2, and 4: look up special relativity on wikipedia. 3: you are at a standstill. do you not have mass? 5: there is no such thing as the center of the universe. 6: we are not moving, nor are the other points. There is simply more space between us and them as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

1 - It is false! If $E = mc^{2}$ is true only for an object that isn’t moving, the mass never changes (is a "Lorentz invariant").

2 - Can you rephrase it, please?

3 - Energy and mass are not at all the same thing; an object’s energy can change when its motion changes, but its mass remains the same.

4 - In Special Relativity, time can be variable, its variation is given by "Lorentz Transformation":

$t'=\frac{t-\frac{vx}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

5 - Noway!!! First: There's no "center of universe". Second: Massive objects never can reach the speed of light, just massless objects can do it!

6 - if the movement is "rectilinear and uniform", it dosen't matter after all. If the movement is accelerated, we will observe some forces we call "pseudo-forces", and it is very usefull to determine if our frame is inertial or not.

Comment: So the solder system is moving right? How do we know this? What other point can we measure this movement from and how do we know that point is not moving as well.

Comment: Solder or Solar?